# Using windows "net use" command from java with win32 api

Tags: java, winapi

I want to build an application on Java using the `Net Use` command.
I'm trying to find a way to do this via a `win32` API (or any other win API).
I would like to use a system call to obtain the information programmatically and not to parse the output of the "net use" command in my Java application.
I've downloaded `jna.jar` and `jna-platform.jar` and tried to find the proper function, but with no success.
Could anyone advise if there's a way to this via system call and/or what function to use from `jna`.
Thanks in advance.
Alex B

Comment: Using the Process class to invoke the command line tool is not an option?

Answer (score 3):

The functions you're looking for reside in the [Windows Networking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the method that best matches what you're looking for is [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add connections, [`WNetOpenEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`WNetEnumResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [`WNetCloseEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate connected/remembered connections.

I've added a simple [github project](https://github.com/petesh/jna-mpr/tree/master) that defines WNetAddConnection2 and WNetCancelConnection.

Comment: Thank a lot for your reply. I didn't understand how can I use this in Java code. Is there any jar to install?

Comment: I ended up here searching for WNetAddConnection2. If someone knows of a java library or jar file for it, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added a reference to a github project that does WNetAddConnection2 via JNA.